# Reagent to reduce aliphatic aldehyde to alcohol while protecting double bond

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, organic-reduction, chemoselectivity

I have a straight chain, aliphatic aldehyde (liquid) with a double bond in it. I want to reduce the terminal carbonyl group to an alcohol but without touching the C=C double bond. The double bond is at a beta position with respect to the end carbonyl group.

Any suggestions whether there are any reactions that may do this?

Below I am showing the configuration of the double bond relative to the end group to avoid confusion.

[image]

Comment: Does NaBH4 not work? Is this on paper, or in practice?

Comment: @orthocresol: Will try. This is at the brainstorming stage. Basically, there's an enzymatic process and I am wondering why they are bothering with expensive finicky enzymes and low yields for this step when we could do it chemically.

Comment: Dibal-H will do this  https://sites.google.com/site/anthonycrastoreagents/diisobutylaluminium-hydride?tmpl=%2Fsystem%2Fapp%2Ftemplates%2Fprint%2F&showPrintDialog=1

Comment: When you say -position, do you mean conjugated or deconjugated?

Comment: @user55119 I was not sure of the question so I posted an image to clarify the position of the double bond.

Comment: You have the (Z)-deconjugated aldehyde. NaBH4 is a good choice but the alkaline conditions in alcohol or water may cause conjugation to the (E)-aldehyde prior to reduction to an (E)-allylic alcohol. I would opt for adding the aldehyde to LiAlH4 in ether.